# Create a function for $\Pi^{-1}(n)$

Tags: function-construction, prime-numbers

Is it possible to create a function that gives the inverse of

```
pP[x_] := Sum[PrimePi[x^(1/k)]/k, {k, 1, Floor[Log2[x]]}]
```

i.e., a function that plots

```
{pP@#, #} & /@ Range@(InverseFunction[LogIntegral][100]) // ListLinePlot
```

but is a function in $n$ that gives the actual value of $\Pi^{-1}(n)$ for any $n?$

Comment: your `pP` only returns a set of discrete rational results. What should the inverse be if evaluated for an `x` not in the set of allowable values?

Comment: @george2079 this is the problem I am facing - intervals should evaluate to the same as the previous value change, but I have no idea how to manage this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an approximation*:

```
inv = Interpolation[
        DeleteDuplicates[ 
            Table[ {pP[x], x}, {x, 1, 400, .01}] , (#1[[1]] == #2[[1]]) & ], 
                 InterpolationOrder -> 0];

Plot[ inv[x], {x, 0, 80}]
```

[image]

The issue now is how to find the exact `x` where the jumps occur..

*After looking at the results the jumps seem to always occur at integer `x`, so you can drop the `.01` increment to speed things up (and I suppose call it exact )

Comment: nice, thanks :) a little slow on my machine - but I suppose that is unavoidable? - Ah, I see, it is the initial calculation to the desired height that is slow - so this function is essentially an interpolation of a lookup table - great - will have a oplay around with it - thanks again :)